# ESLint couldn't find the config "google" to extend from. Please check that the name of the config is correct

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, eslint

I'm trying to deploy a cloud function on firebase. I'm successfully logged into firebase CLI from osx terminal. When I go to deploy it kicks back this error.

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 7.19.0

ESLint couldn't find the config "google" to extend from. Please check that the name of the config is correct.
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem

Answer (score 32):

it's because you didn't do the install

```
Would you like to install them now with npm? · No / Yes
```

you can try again configuring json .eslint or you can do it this way

```
npm install eslint-config-google --save-dev
```

Comment: Your exactly knew what I did xD, Thanks for the answer

Comment: If you're using yarn, you should run `yarn add -D eslint-config-google`

Answer (score 5):

As explained here: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#using-a-configuration-from-a-plugin

> The `extends` property value can consist of:
>
> - `plugin:`
> - the package name (from which you can omit the prefix, for example, `react` is short for `eslint-plugin-react`)
> - `/`
> - the configuration name (for example, `recommended`)

Meaning, if you extend your config using the google plugin like this in your `.eslintrc.yml`:

```yaml
extends:
  - google
```

you have to install it doing:
`npm install eslint-config-google --save-dev`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, While trying to debug my error I happen to make some changes in the below code, reverting it back to this way removed the error

Please check in your .eslintrc.js ,if the below code is there or not

**extends: ["eslint:recommended", "google"],**

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you do not have eslint installed so try to install it by running this command:

`npm install eslint-config-eslint --save-dev`

Comment: the error above kicked backed the ESLint version so I assumed it was installed. I will run that command just to make sure and try and re deploy.

Answer (score 0):

After making sure that ESLint is installed, you just need to initialize it by running:

```
eslint --init
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and resolved mine running this:

```
npm install eslint-config-eslint --save-dev
```

Most likely you didn't have eslint-config-google installed.
Once installed try running ESLint again.